# SQL Select entries that fulfill the maximum number of conditions

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the entries from a database that fulfill multiple conditions.

However I don't know if there is any entry that fulfill all the conditions but I still want to get the entries that fulfill the maximum number of conditions.

For example I want a pizza that has tomato sauce, cheese, pepperoni, bacon and mushrooms.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Pizzas 
WHERE Sauce = tomato 
  AND Cheese = true 
  AND Pepperoni = true 
  AND Bacon = true 
  AND Mushrooms = true
```

Returns nothing.

But I still want the pizza that can fulfill the maximum of these conditions.

I was thinking about doing something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Pizzas 
WHERE Sauce = tomato 
   OR Cheese = true 
   OR Pepperoni = true 
   OR Bacon = true 
   OR Mushrooms = true
```

And then ordering by the number of conditions met.

But I don't know if it is possible and if so, how to do that?

Comment: `tomato` is a column named tomato. `'tomato'` is a string literal, containing tomato.

Comment: The boolean test syntax should be `column IS TRUE`.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by the conditions that match:

```
SELECT *
FROM Pizzas
WHERE (CASE WHEN Sauce=tomato THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Cheese=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Pepperoni=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Bacon=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Mushrooms=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Depending on your database, you might have slightly different syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about the case statement :)